# No length contraction in thought experiment with co-moving measuring stick

Tags: special-relativity, measurements

Suppose a person standing on a platform were to observe and measure the length of a train passing by. Instead of the usual approach involving a clock and knowing the speed of the train, the person uses a measuring tape. The tape is designed to stick, such that as the front of the train passes us, we stick it to the front of the train, and as the tape head touches the rear, it breaks off. Now, by measuring the length of the tape that is missing from the role, we can calculate the length of the train.

But this length will be equal to the 'rest length' of the train. Hence, from the perspective of a person on the train, there was no length contraction in our measurement!

This doesn't seem right. Is there anything wrong in my analysis?

Comment: The tape will be moving and will therefore length contract.

Comment: you need to use a tape that is a rest in your reference frame, which is not satisfied in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.

If in your experiment, the tape is placed parallel to the rails in such a way that when the train passes (A), it grabs the tape and it "sticks" along the train "instantaneously", then the following happens:

A person in terrain, before (A) sees a static normal-size tape and a contracted train approaching fast, after (A) he/she sees the same contracted train carrying a tape that is also contracted, so it measures the correct "static" train length, because both the train and the tape are contracted in the same proportion.

A person in the train, before (A), sees the train in normal-size going fast towards a contracted tape. After (A) he/she sees the tape attached to the train, both of them with normal size, so again, it measures the correct train length.

Maybe it is a confusion produced by the [Reality of the length contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction#Reality_of_length_contraction):

1. It is not real in the sense that the train is actually contracted.
   It cannot be, at the same time, both contracted (from the
   perspective of a person in terrain) and no contracted (from the
   perspective of a person inside the train).
2. It is real in the sense that any measurement will report a length contraction of the train from the perspective of a person on the terrain. No matter the method you use (visual, using instruments, clocks or tapes, etc.), and no matter how hard you try to improve accuracy in order to prove that there is no contraction (number 1), a length contraction will always be reported.

Several experiments have been designed, like yours, (I also designed mine!!!), to produce a contradiction, for example [the ladder paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox), but all they are usually solved when taking account the relativity of simultaneity.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in stating what you will measure on the (now moving) measuring tape. To see the difference, imagine that the measuring tape in your frame was the length of the train station. The moment it attaches to the train and is moving at the same velocity as the train, however, it will appear shorter than the train station.